# De Rham Cohomology Question

Tags: differential-topology

Let $M$ be a compact connected $n$-manifold without boundary. Let $\mu\in\Omega^{n-1}(M)$, show that there exists a point $p\in M$ such that $d\mu(p)=0$.

Comment: You can typeset mathematics as in LaTeX on this website: enclose mathematics in `$` or `$$` as appropriate. But please consider phrasing your question *as a question*, not as an order.

Answer (score 8):

First, assume that $M$ is oriented.  Then, by Stokes's theorem, we have $\int_M d\mu = \int_{\partial M} \mu = 0$ since $\partial M = \emptyset$.  This can't happen if $d\mu$ is never $0$.

If $M$ is nonorientable, let $N$ by any orientable cover of $M$ (say, the universal cover, or the orientation covering).  Let $\pi:N\rightarrow M$ be the covering map.

Then by the previous case, $d(\pi^*\mu)$ is $0$ on some point $p$ of $N$.  But $0 = d(\pi^*\mu) = \pi^* (d\mu)$.  Since $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism, $\pi^*$ induces an isomorphism from $\Omega(M)_{\pi(p)}\rightarrow \Omega(N)_{p}$.  Since the image of $d\mu$ under this isomorphism is $0$, we must have $d\mu(\pi(p)) = 0$.

Comment: On second thought, one should definitely use the orientation covering as the universal cover may not be compact.